# Curl function does not return response

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I want to call a Api. I have used Curl for this and made a library. When i call the Curl library function from controller, it returns NULL but if i print the response it displays the data. Can anyone help me?

```
My Curl Library code :
    public function callApi($jwt_tkn, $url, $postdata, $method)
    {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer ' . $jwt_tkn));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: check `curl_error()` like `if(curl_error($ch))
{
    echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch);
}` place it before `$result = curl_exec($ch);`

Comment: Also:-`When i call the Curl library function from controller, it returns NULL but if i print the response it displays the data`:- i din't get this part?

Comment: Show your controller code. Where are your "printing" the data to see the correct response?

Comment: public function index()
{
 $data['users_relative'] = $this->Api->callApi($token, 'http://abcd.com/get/relative', array('user_id' => $user_id), 'post');
 print_r($data['users_relative']);
}

Comment: @Utkarsha Can you please add that code to your question. Can you show what works and what doesn't work. It might help explain things better for us.